# Não chama a class Startup, Owin

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, owin

Minha API não esta chamando a minha classe Startup, consequentemente não chama o meu controller via Postman.

**Startup**

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(GestaoFrotas.Security.API.Startup))]

namespace GestaoFrotas.Security.API
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            //configuração WebApi
            var config = new HttpConfiguration();

            //configurando rotas
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                 name: "DefaultApi",
                 routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                 defaults: new { id = System.Web.Http.RouteParameter.Optional }
             );

            ConfigureAccessToken(app);

            // ativando configuração WebApi
            app.UseWebApi(config);
        }
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/Autenticacao/ConfirmEmail")]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> ConfirmEmail(string userId = "", string code = "")
{

}
```

Alguém pode me ajudar nessa questão, ja refiz o projeto e nada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvi adicionando a biblioteca abaixo:

Install-Package Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb